# OpenGL: What's the best way to convert a screen coordinate to a world coordinate?

Tags: opengl, coordinates, depth-buffer

For example, suppose I'm building a first-person shooter and the player pulls the trigger. I want to convert the screen coordinate `(x, y)` into a world coordinate `(x, y, z)` to know what they've hit.

I've seen some people mentioning a lookup using `glReadPixels`, but I've heard it's slow and those references were years old, so I'm not sure if this is the best way.

I'm working with core OpenGL 3.3, not ES. `gluUnProject` is not part of the API I'm asking about.

These types of answers would be most helpful:

- An explanation of how to retrive a pixel's `(x, y, z)` value using `glReadPixels` and how to transform that into world coordinates. I know how to multiply by inverse matrices; I don't know *exactly* what steps OpenGL takes to arrive at its depth buffer value.
- Or, an explantion of how to do something similar, perhaps more efficiently, with a pixel buffer object.
- Or some method that I don't even know about that's better than either of the above.

For some context: I have many months' worth of code into a game I'm developing in OpenGL using the core 3.3 profile. I'm using minimal libraries and not the old fixed-function GL pipeline, which is why it does not make sense for me to use `gluUnProject`. I mention this to highlight why this question is not the duplicate of a currently-linked older question.

*Note: I previously mentioned a shader idea that did not add much to the question, so I removed it. I also edited the question to clarify the context and the type of answer I am looking for.*

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to implement picking. There are several questions about this on the site, including [this one](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26292/opengl-es-2-0-gluunproject), which shows you how to do it via gluUnproject (the references to ES 2 are a red-herring here as this technique applies to "regular" OpenGL as well).

Comment: Why do you want to convert coordinates in fragment shader? You given an example about pulling a trigger, however the fact of pulling usually is detected on cpu side. Please describe in detail, what are these screen coordinates and how are they calculated.

Comment: You don't *need* `gluUnproject`; you can see from the documentation that all it does is simple matrix multiplication and math. The basic technique is the same, you can just unroll the function (see, for example, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193703/how-to-do-picking-in-modern-opengl-without-gluunproject)).

Comment: Thank you for the tip, Josh. I do not know a good way to retrieve the depth buffer value in order to perform the reverse projection. I guess I could investigate `glReadPixels`, but I'm wondering if there is a faster way. If not, I'm wondering if there is a good way to learn how to use this function - I find the official docs heard to learn from. I've also seen references to pixel buffer objects, so I thought they might be another alternative.

Comment: You shouldn't need a depth buffer value. Just unproject twice: first (x, y, 0) and then (x,y, 1); this gives you two points in object space you can use to create a ray, and anything that intersects with that ray is something the mouse "hit."

Comment: I would like to request that this question be re-opened. I understand that its first version did appear to be a duplicate of the marked question, but that was simply because I had left out some critical details - mainly about which OpenGL version I am using. I have edited the question to clarify why it is different from the currently-linked previous question. I do appreciate the helpful comments. I would still find value in seeing what the gamedev community at large has to say. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see what separates this question from the duplicate or [any of the similar questions on doing 3D picking on the site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=3d+picking). The answer is still the same. We don't want to collect a bunch of questions that of the form "how can I do X in API Y" and "how can I do X in API Z," in general. I need you to further distinguish the question before I'd feel comfortable unilaterally re-opening. For example, do you want to know *explicitly* how to do picking using glReadPixels (knowing that this is perhaps not the most optimal solution)?

Comment: This question is about how to accomplish a specific task with a specific API. The linked question is about another API. It seems valid to me based on the type of questions suggested in the gamedev tour [1] - specifically, it fits well into "game-specific programming issues (engine architecture, game-related APIs, networking, tools, etc)." Jumping to an abstract level, this discussion makes me feel that my question is seen as "stupid until proven worthy." This kind of interaction pushes away people who otherwise may add a lot of value to the site. [1] http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18024/discussion-between-josh-petrie-and-tyler).